# Spring Android REST Template parse JSON data with Content Type text/html

Tags: android, jackson, spring-android

I'm using android spring REST template to extract some data from external APIs.
those APIs return JSON string but response content type is "text/html", If the content type is "application/json" I can easily parse data without any issue, since this APIs are 3rd party APIs I can't change the content type of the response.

I'm using 
    "MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"
 class as the message converter.

I'm getting below exception when I try to parse data.

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type .... and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
```

Is there any configuration,parameter or something where I can parse these JSON data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` only supports the `application/json` media type. However, you can easily configure it to support other media types:

```
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
```

Now when you receive the response, `RestTemplate` should identify `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` as being able to parse it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer, this is what i've been looking for. :)